# Where did I go wrong in my calculation? (Complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers, maple

So I am doing an assignment where I have to (by hand) multiply two numbers (z1 and z2) in polar form. Afterwards I have to check that I am getting the same result as Maple.

[image]

Maple gives me different polar coordinates than my manuel calculation though. Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your picture correctly, the answer that you got is$$2\left(\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}6\right)+\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}6\right)i\right),\tag1$$whereas Maple got$$2\left(\cos\left(-\frac{5\pi}6\right)+\sin\left(-\frac{5\pi}6\right)i\right).\tag2$$Am I right? If so, what's the problem? After all, $(1)=(2)$.

Comment: Well...this is embarrassing. You are absolutely right :) I don't know why I didn't notice that, thanks!